# Transfering the parachain slot to other parachain

Tags: parachain, auctions, slot

For curiosity, if one organization wins the slot in the parachain auction, can it transfer the slot to another parachain? Or if I deregister the parachain, is the slot also released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1:

> If one organization wins the slot in the parachain auction, can it
> transfer the slot to another parachain?

Yes, you can do it via `registrar.swap`, it's on relaychain, and most parachains renew their leases through it.

For question 2:

> If I deregister the parachain, is the slot also released?

**<del>Yes</del>**, it will free any data, and return any deposits made by the parachain.

### Update

Sorry, my fault. I accidentally discovered during testing that deregister **does not clear the lease of paraId**. Here are the steps I took:

1. slots.forceLease(2105, 0, 999)
2. parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize(2105)
3. degistrar.deregister(2105)
4. parasSudoWrapper.sudoScheduleParaInitialize(2105)
5. paraId 2105 still has the lease from step 1.

And I checked [the `do_deregister` code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.38/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L602) and indeed found that the leases storage was not cleaned.